# Will this character appear in another movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In *Avengers: Age of Ultron*

> Pietro Maximoff (aka Quicksilver) is shot and killed whilst saving Hawkeye and a child in Sokovia.

Marvel has a long history of

> bringing characters back from the dead

Is there anything from the rich annals of the Marvel comics to suggest that we might see them again?

Comment: I think there've been some problem with the rights to use the character between Marvel Studios (Avengers saga) and Sony Pictures (X-men Saga). So maybe we'll see him in the future "X-Men: Apocalypse" movie.

Comment: @Bardo the licensing issues for the characters in question are well documented on this site, among others; at any rate, they are two different characters, so the death of one has nothing to do with future appearances of the other.

Comment: I appreciate the spoiler-free title. Most of the time it seems like someone watches a movie, immediately comes here and says 'Clawman died at the end of The Clawening, why would Mrs Claw laugh?' instead of censoring their title. Thank you.

Comment: Shit man, I was just about to see "The Clawening". Thanks for ruiniing it *jerk!*

Comment: Don't worry, he comes back in The Clawening 2: Claw Harder

Comment: What are you doing @maguirenumber6, now you went and spoiled *The Clawening 2* too!

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield, of course, I mean that probably Marvel Studios decided to kill him on it's universe because they don't have the rights to continue using the character.

Comment: I heard NBC just announced he's coming back in a crime series, Claw and Order.   Sorry for the spoiler.

Comment: I heavily disapprove of this question. The fact that some character appears in some other movie is a huge spoiler that the movie industry is going to continue for another year. Thanks for NOTHING, dude. (Seriously, at this stage I'm probably boring everyone here with my hardline stance that this kind of heavy handed anti-spoiler titles are stupid :( )

Answer (score 24):

Highly unlikely, based on the following account from a [Q&A with Kevin Feige](http://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/350fsy/kevin_feige_on_avengers_age_of_ultron_will/):

> Quiksilver is ***DEAD***. 100%, he's not coming back any time soon, there are no plans. 
> No LMD, no escaping bullets, no retcon. 
> Kevin Feige said he is dead and wanted to make sure people understood that.

Answer (score 19):

Probably not (unfortunately).

Both Kevin Fiege and Joss Whedon have gone on record stating that after Phil Coulson's revival, bringing additional characters back from the dead would prevent the films from being able to build any real tension.

Additionally, multiple characters from *Avengers: Age of Ultron* have been announced to appear in the upcoming *Captain America: Civil War* - the character in question is not one of them.

Overall, we can't really say for certain though - we already know that there is at least one way to bring characters back from the dead in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, and with Scarlet Witch having immensely powerful reality bending abilities (at least in the comics) and *Avengers: Infinity War* set to join the Infinity Stones in the Power Gauntlet, I'm not over exaggerating when I say that literally anything could happen.

Comment: " would stop the films from being able to build any real tension." - it hasn't stopped the comics. They used to say the only comic characters that stay dead are Bucky, Jean Grey, Uncle Ben, and Gwen Stacy. Guess why they don't say that anymore.

Comment: I once saw a joke comic where Uncle Ben was complaining that everyone else gets to come back to life but not he.

Answer (score 4):

In the Marvel Studios universe? Seems that he won't.

> However, Evan Peters will be reprising the role in [X-Men: Apocalypse](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3385516/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_1). So, hey, you get a speedster somewhere!

Comment: Considering the spoilers elsewhere, you might want to hide the last 2 sentences.

Comment: This answer is almost like saying "Well, The Flash has a second season coming up, so you don't have to worry about lack of speedsters!"